# Convert Time with AM/PM and +UCT (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert 
`'11/09/2011 11:33:00 PM +0000'` (object) into a datetime variable using Pandas' `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'],format = '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', utc=True)
```

however getting a error back:

> "duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `+0000` is fixed you can add it to the format string like:

#### Code:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p +0000', utc=True)
```

#### Test Code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([
    '11/09/2011 11:33:00 PM +0000',
    '11/09/2011 11:33:00 PM +0000',
    '11/09/2011 11:33:00 PM +0000',
    ], columns=['Datetime'])
print(df)

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Datetime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p +0000', utc=True)
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
                       Datetime
0  11/09/2011 11:33:00 PM +0000
1  11/09/2011 11:33:00 PM +0000
2  11/09/2011 11:33:00 PM +0000

                   Datetime
0 2011-09-11 23:33:00+00:00
1 2011-09-11 23:33:00+00:00
2 2011-09-11 23:33:00+00:00
```